# To blacklist an IP in AWS do we need to create IPSet for client or for Client Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a client IP that I need to black list. Do I need to create IPset for a client or client Environment?

Comment: Adding more information to your question will help people to answer (is it an IP range, or a single address? Do you have a VPC? Do you want to block access to all resources, or a single EC2?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your EC2 instance and network is configured it's difficult to say. However, this answer assumes that you are trying to blacklist an IP address for your entire VPC rather than the EC2 instance only.

Security at the network level can be managed by a [Network Access Control List (NACL)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) or [SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html). NACL's allow `ALLOW` and `DENY` rules; SecurityGroups only have `ALLOW` rules.

So, to blacklist an IP you can use a NACL inbound rule with the IP range and `DENY`.

```
|Rule #|Type       |Protocol|Port range|Source       |Allow/Deny|
|------|-----------|--------|----------|-------------|----------|
|200   |All traffic|All     |All       |192.0.1.0/32 |DENY      |
```

For more advanced scenarios you may need to look at running something like [AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/network-firewall.html)